# Will the file be closed after returning from function?

Tags: python, file, zip

Here is a python function:

```
def read_data(filename):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    for name in f.namelist():
        return tf.compat.as_str(f.read(name))
    f.close()
```

Will the file be closed? There is no error when calling it.

Comment: I don't really understand the indentation here, you're probably going to get a syntax error or an unexpected interpretation of your program. Why is the `for` statement indented relative to the preceding variable declaration?

Comment: Also, if you fix the indentation, the answer is no, the file won't be closed. You should use a `with` clause here so that the file handle is automatically disposed once you leave the scope.

Comment: Your code also wouldn't iterate through the `namelist` as you `return` from the first iteration... you might want to look at generators and `yield` if you are looking for more than one result from this function.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I am pretty sure python won't execute the print method after return, but not convinced about close file.

Comment: @AChampion there is only one element in the namelist, so that's not a big problem.

Comment: @C.Zion Python won't execute anything after return, there is no special allowance made for methods called `close`.

Comment: C.Zion and @Asad: If there is a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) in effect (via a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)), then its `__exit__()` method will automatically be called when the function returns. Files are context managers, and in their case if one was opened in a `with`, then it _will_ be closed automatically. As of Python 2.7, `ZipFile`s are also context managers, so they now provide similar `with` statement support.

Comment: @martineau Yes, that's great, but the file is not opened with `with`, and hence will not be closed at the end of the function, which is the answer to the question. I mentioned the use of `with` in an earlier comment.

Comment: @Asad: Sorry...should have only addressed my comment to C.Zion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file won't be closed. If you want to close the file, you can write it like:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
        for name in f.namelist():
            return tf.compat.as_str(f.read(name))
```

Testing your code:
[image: picture shows that the file wasn't closed]

Testing the code with `with`:
[image: picture shows that the file has been closed]

Comment: Technically, in CPython, the `close` occurs implicitly when the last reference to the file-like object is released (e.g. on function return if no other references stored), but that's an artifact of CPython's reference counting (and it could be temporarily foiled by something as simple as an exception preserving locals in the traceback frame); you should always use `with` blocks whenever possible to get predictable closing behavior, so it can't be forgotten or skipped by accident.

Comment: @wolframalpha Thank you!